# Embedding Hyperlinks Using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, google-pie-chart

I'm using two divs to show custom tooltips for a Google pie chart. The first is a column of text, and the second is a column of URLs corresponding to the text. Is it possible to embed the URLs in the text instead and present clickable hyperlinks when a pie slice is selected?

Here's the chart's datasource: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPG22Q75rsvrjzqIKzSuaggpRIRVYTOp8JzuIxM7UBQ/edit?usp=sharing

And here's the pie chart itself for more context: http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/u2ydom1q/3/

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {
                packages: ["corechart"]
            });
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


            function drawChart() {
                var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPG22Q75rsvrjzqIKzSuaggpRIRVYTOp8JzuIxM7UBQ/gviz/tq?gid=967749684');
                query.setQuery('select A,B,C,D');
                query.send(handleQueryResponse);
            }

            function handleQueryResponse(response) {
                if (response.isError()) {
                    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                    return;
                }
                var data = response.getDataTable();
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                view.setColumns([0, 1]);

                var options = {
                    legend: 'none',
                    title: 'Countries',
                    chartArea: {
                        left: 10,
                        top: 20,
                        width: "92%",
                        height: "100%"
                    },
                    width: 400,
                    height: 400,
                    is3D: 'true',
                    enableInteractivity: 'true',
                    pieSliceText: 'label',
                    fontSize: 10,
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
                document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(view, options);

                var selectHandler = function(e) {
                    var firsttooltipDiv = document.getElementById('firsttooltip_div');
                    firsttooltipDiv.innerHTML = "";
                    var firstlines = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 2).split('\n');
                    for (var i = 0; i < firstlines.length; i++) {
                        var firstlineDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        firstlineDiv.textContent = firstlines[i];
                        firsttooltipDiv.appendChild(firstlineDiv);
                    }


                    var secondtooltipDiv = document.getElementById('secondtooltip_div');
                    secondtooltipDiv.innerHTML = "";
                    var secondlines = data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 3).split('\n');
                    for (var i = 0; i < secondlines.length; i++) {
                        var secondlineDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        secondlineDiv.textContent = secondlines[i];
                        secondtooltipDiv.appendChild(secondlineDiv);
                    }

                }

                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table style="font-size:smaller">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; align: center">
                    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 450px; height: 400px"></div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; align: left; white-space=nowrap; font-weight:bold">
                    <div id="firsttooltip_div"></div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; align: left; white-space=nowrap">
                    <div id="secondtooltip_div"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where are you expecting the links on the chart, or at the right top that you're displaying after clicking on pie slice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links we can show at top right corner as follows
**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2ydom1q/4/)**

Handler function chaned as follows:

```
  var selectHandler = function(e) {
    var row = chart.getSelection()[0].row;
    var titles = data.getValue(row, 2).split('\n');
    var urls = data.getValue(row, 3).split('\n');

    var linksDiv = document.getElementById('firsttooltip_div');
    linksDiv.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.textContent = titles[i];
      link.setAttribute("href", urls[i] || 'javascript:void(0)');
      link.style.display = "block";
      linksDiv.appendChild(link);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Venkata. That's precisely what I was after!

Comment: Venkata, do you know if it's also possible to use a cell from the datasource spreadsheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPG22Q75rsvrjzqIKzSuaggpRIRVYTOp8JzuIxM7UBQ/edit?usp=sharing) as the HTML table's header—i.e. `<th><div id="tableheader_div"></th>`? I've been unsuccessful creating a working div; here's what I've tried so far, attempting to make cell A1 my table's title: http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/u2ydom1q/5/

Comment: SpreadSheet data is only for datasource(i.e., for `dataTable`) and best place to set title or header or caption is in `handleQueryResponse`, `selectHandler` function not right place to do that. Why don't you use `var options = {title: 'My chart Title', ...}`.

Comment: You may try to get value at A1 as `data.getColumnLabel(0)` but it combines both A1 and A2 values.

Comment: Now I see. Including something like...
    `var head = data.getColumnLabel(0);
     var headerDiv = document.getElementById('header_div');
     headerDiv.textContent = head;`
...in the selectHandler() function means the div will only appear when the table fires the "select" event: http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/u2ydom1q/7/
Instead, I'll add a ready event (and rearrange my spreadsheet column labels) to get the desired results: http://jsfiddle.net/gregpearl/u2ydom1q/8/
Thank you again for all your help, sir!